# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, haml

I currently have this code:

```
- if @ue.id = 1

  = form_tag("/about-us/upcoming-events/process", :id => "theoneform") do
    %table.cellone
      %input{ :type => "hidden", :value => "#{ @ue.title }", :name => "upcoming_event" }
      %input{ :type => "hidden", :value => "#{ @ue.campaign_id }", :name => "campaign_id"}
      %input{ :type => "hidden", :value => "#{ @ue.date }", :name => "event_date" }


      - "1,2,3,4,19,20,260, 263, 265,237,45".split(",").each do |ff3|
        = raw make_me_a_field(ff3, @form_info)

- else if @ue.id = 6

  = form_tag("/about-us/upcoming-events/process", :id => "theoneform") do
    %table.cellone
      %input{ :type => "hidden", :value => "#{ @ue.title }", :name => "upcoming_event" }
      %input{ :type => "hidden", :value => "#{ @ue.campaign_id }", :name => "campaign_id"}
      %input{ :type => "hidden", :value => "#{ @ue.date }", :name => "event_date" }


      - "1,2,3,4,19,20,260,237,45".split(",").each do |ff3|
        = raw make_me_a_field(ff3, @form_info)
```

and I'm getting this error:

`syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end`

I assume it's to do with the indentation but I can't see the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the if statement, you're doing an assignment with '=', we should use '==' instead.

And I think you need to use 'elsif' instead of 'else if'.

Comment: Hi, I've changed that like you said, but i still get this error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end`

Comment: Not sure why this comment was accepted as the answer when it is not the answer. There's a more likely answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715290/rails-syntax-error-unexpected-keyword-ensure-expecting-keyword-end