# Rails syntax error: unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

```
<h1>Get Ready</h1>
<% if params[:ballot_position].to_i > 1 %>
<p>
Voter <%= params[:ballot_position].to_i - 1 %>, go get voter <%= params[:ballot_position] %>
and switch places with them.
</p>
<p>
Voter <%= params[:ballot_position] %>, when you are ready, click the button marked "Ready" below.
</p>
<% @ballot_link = "/vote/#{params[:election_id]}/ballot/#{params[:ballot_position]}" %>
<a href="<%= @ballot_link %>" class="btn btn-primary">Ready</a>
```

Above code seems to be resulting in:

```
ready.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
ready.html.erb:15: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

What's going on? What's wrong with this syntax?

Comment: You posted line 10 and 11 of the file, while the error is referencing line 13 and 15. Could you please post some more context around the lines you posted?

Comment: syntax error in line number 13 , but here line 10 & 11 are showing

Comment: @henrikhodne, There is no line 13.  11 is the last line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The errors you're receiving more than likely stem from trying to execute a if-else conditional wherein you have an extra `<% end %>` *before* `<% else %>`. Ensure that your conditional follows canonical *if-else-end* logic like the following:

```
<% if ... %>
    <% @ballot_link = "/vote/#{params[:election_id]}/ballot/#{params[:ballot_position]}" %>
    <a href="<%= @ballot_link %>" class="btn btn-primary">Ready</a>
<% else %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I forgot an `<% end %>`.  Thanks.

Comment: Note: Rails was complaining about one file, while my missing `end` statement was in another file.

Comment: I called an if as block: `<% if (condition) do %>...<% end %>`, but there shouldn't be a `do` ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

You are using if condition. So you should end it. The basic if conditions syntax for erb is

```
<% if ...condition.. %>
    Statement
<% end %>
```

You have to decide what are you using ? It is if condition or if-else condition

In you case, there is not <% end %> clause at end so you have to add it.

```
<h1>Get Ready</h1>
<% if params[:ballot_position].to_i > 1 %>
<p>
Voter <%= params[:ballot_position].to_i - 1 %>, go get voter <%= params[:ballot_position] %>
and switch places with them.
</p>
<p>
Voter <%= params[:ballot_position] %>, when you are ready, click the button marked "Ready" below.
</p>
<% @ballot_link = "/vote/#{params[:election_id]}/ballot/#{params[:ballot_position]}" %>
<a href="<%= @ballot_link %>" class="btn btn-primary">Ready</a> 

<% end %>  # this is what you have to add
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I forgot to end a do block when creating a link using link_to. My incorrect code looked like:

```
      <%= link_to("#", :class => "example-class") do %>
        Nested HTML goes here
```

I had forgotten to end the do statement. The correct code looks like:

```
      <%= link_to("#", :class => "example-class") do %>
        Nested HTML goes here
      <% end %>
```

Hope this helps someone.