# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input.

I made sure the syntax is correct (I think).

I checked with a binding.pry in the controller and @redirect_url is equal to the following: @redirect_url = "http://localhost:3333/articles/medicine/test"

```
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.location.href = '<%=j @redirect_url %>';
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Full error stack please

Comment: I think the error is not with the code you posted up.  That error usually is associated with an `if` or `if-else` block that has not been closed, ie doesn't have an `end`.   Or, maybe an extra `end` in your code somewhere.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715290/rails-syntax-error-unexpected-keyword-ensure-expecting-keyword-end

Comment: Hey Max you're right. It was a missing end in a partial somewhere else